# From a SWF, play youtube video in lightbox without any code external to the swf

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to build a Flash banner ad which will be hosted on a site I have no access to. My client would like to have a button which, when clicked, would open a youtube video in a lightbox frame. I've been looking all around, but all I see that seems workable involves my being able to edit the html page. I am trying to do this with AS3 and Javascript. Some solutions involve JQuery, but I am not a JQuery pro.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lightbox is a jquery function. The only way you could do it is if the jquery library is being loaded. Let alone the plethora of crossdomain issues.

The only way I know of doing what you want would be to create the javaScript code inside of your flash app.
I would assume it could be possible to include an entire library inside this anonymous function.

```
var script:XML = <script>  
<![CDATA[  
// Your JavaScript code here  
]]>  
</script>;  

ExternalInterface.call(script);
```